# Serverless Detect Running Locally

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am running a command like the following.

```
serverless invoke local --function twilio_incoming_call
```

When I run locally in my code I plan to detect this and instead of looking for POST variables look for a MOCK file I'll be giving it.

I don't know how to detect if I'm running serverless with this local command however.

**How do you do this?**

I looked around on the serverless website and could find lots of info about running in local but not detecting *if you were in local.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out the answer.  `process.env.IS_LOCAL` will detect if you are running locally.  Missed this on their website somehow...

Comment: Good catch! This is the link to the Serverless doc: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke-local/#environment

Answer (score 6):

If you're using AWS Lambda, it has some built-in environment variables. In the absence of those variables, then you can conclude that your function is running locally.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-environment-variables.html

```
const isRunningLocally = !process.env.AWS_EXECUTION_ENV
```

This method works regardless of the framework you use whether you are using serverless, Apex UP, AWS SAM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check what is in `process.argv`:

`process.argv[1]` will equal '/usr/local/bin/sls'

`process.argv[2]` will equal 'invoke'

`process.argv[3]` will equal 'local'