# Know when running lambda locally

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Is there a way with the AWS CLI to tell that you are running your lambda locally programmatically?  I'm trying to avoid adding extra data in the request.

I have some functionality that I don't want kicked off when I'm running locally, but I do once its up in the AWS cloud.

Thanks

Comment: so i did finally find this.  so far it looks like AWS_EXECUTION_ENV is the most functional (still trying to test)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255681/serverless-detect-running-locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first option is to use [one of the environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime) that are available when a Lambda function is executed. The `AWS_EXECUTION_ENV` - like you stated in your comment - can be a good pick for this.

A second option is using [the context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) which is passed in as a second parameter to your handler function. This contains very specific information about the request, such as the `awsRequestId` which could also help you in determining whether or not your code is running on the cloud or locally.

Comment: The AWS did work for me.  Was still having issues with the context, cause it was still connecting and using AWS services.  But to be fair, I didn't dig in to deep once AWS_EXECUTION_ENV solved the problem.  :)